# How to auto-expand query results in TFS / DevOps dashboard?

Tags: tfs, devops, dashboard

I have created a dashboard in Azure DevOps with a query widget.
The query lists all work-items that have been wrongfully linked to a certain Feature.
By default the result is not expanded and I have to manually expand it each time.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the Query is the data source for the widget. Unlike the result in the query editor, the linked work items will not auto expand.

Unfortunately, there are also not any related configuration could change this. It's by default.

You could raise a feature request in our user voice site: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/visual-studio-team-services.html?type=idea

Our PM will regularly review it there. Kindly monitor and vote up it.